# selenium c# instance of an object error

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

there selenium web drive c # but I create the code in the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error How was I supposed to regular code? Can you help please?

```
    private void Modul4_Siteimage()
    {        
        try
        {
            IWebDriver driver = webDriverSelect(comboBox_Browser.Text); //browser seçilir                   


            for (int i = 0; i < lst_Result.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(lst_Result.Items[i+1].ToString()); //link seçilir


                foreach (var item in driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("lazyOwl")))
                {

                    if (doesImageExistRemotely(item.GetAttribute("src").ToString(), "image/jpeg"))
                        {
                            lst_Result.Items.Add("Doğru " + lst_Result.Items[i].ToString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lst_Result.Items.Add("HATA " + lst_Result.Items[i].ToString());
                        }

                }

            }
            driver.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception exx)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hata " + exx.Message);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `.ToString()` of `null` for the last iteration of for loop by `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(lst_Result.Items[i+1].ToString());`.  You may change the loop as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lst_Result.Items.Count-1; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 5 items in lst_Result.

This line:

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(lst_Result.Items[i+1].ToString());
```

Is referring to item 6, which does not exist.
The `for` loop iterates `i` to 4, which is the last iteration before it is no longer `< lst_Results.Items.Count`. So `i == 4`, and `[i + 1] == 5`. However an `array` starts at 0. So if there are 5 Items in `lst_Result`, the final entry is 4. (0, 1, 2, 3, 4) In your last iteration it checks location '5' in the array. Which is `null`, and cannot be converted `.ToString()`.